# Excluding data points from Tableau trend chart

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to make a trend chart that has two lines on it. The first is a sum of a field over time, except for one data point that I want to exclude from the sum of two years, and the other is a summation of a subset of rows.

For example:

```
+--------+------+--------+
| FRUIT  | YEAR | NUMBER |
+--------+------+--------+
| Apple  | 2012 | 2      |
| Banana | 2012 | 3      |
| Pear   | 2012 | 2      |
| Apple  | 2013 | 3      |
| Banana | 2013 | 3      |
| Pear   | 2013 | 3      |
+--------+------+--------+
```

I would want one line to be the sum of all three fruit over time, but to exclude pears in 2013, and the second line to be Apples and Bananas over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should work.

Line 1:

```
sum(if [Fruit] = "Pear" and [Year] = 2013 then null else [Number] end)
```

Line 2:

```
sum(if [Fruit]!="Pear" then [Number] end)
```

Comment: Thanks Bernardo! I actually ended up using an IIF statement, but I tested your and it provides the same answer as the solution I came up with. I don't know if there are any drawbacks to doing it with an IIF statement... If there are, please let me know!

Comment: You're welcome. Depending on the data, there isn't much difference between IF THEN and IIF. IIF gives you the flexibility to account for an unknown. Check out this article for a great description on IF and CASE. https://www.interworks.com/blog/tmcconnell/2015/02/10/case-statements-vs-if-statements-tableau